# how to set dynamic height for hamburger navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am working on an application where i need to redesigning navigation bar. I have completed the same but the problem is height issue occurring in different pages. for example in below snapshot,the height of navigation bar is perfect in `login page`, but in `registration page` the height of navigation bar is not fully covered till footer.

[image: login page]

[image: registration page]

```css
nav {
  /* height: 15vh; */
  height: 91px;
  background: #ffd415;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffd415;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: #424242;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Raleway-Bold;
}

.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #424242;
  margin: 5px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-links {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffd415;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 665px;
  /* height: 100vh; */
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -15%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -15%);
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-links.open {
  clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
}

li.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo-left {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  color: #424242;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-left">
    <label class="logo">Marshamllow</label>
  </div>
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

it seems because of fixed height i have given i,e `665px`, i want to know the way to set the height dynamicallly so if page content becomes increase then navigation bar should be uniform across all the pages, please suggest me the best practice for achieving the same.

Please refer Jsfiddle for the same:-
https://jsfiddle.net/aparnabhargav/k3tjeod6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `vh` units which will cover the window height. More [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/)

if the height of your footer is fixed, even better. something like:

```
nav {
    height:calc(100vh - XXpx); /*where "XX" is footer height*/
}
```